# Check the product category/id before add it to the cart (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, product

Im looking to make a function must do that, example:

I have 10 categories, 3 of them are special, their name are: "Alpha", "Bravo" and "Charlie"

In the function I must have an array with the category ID of the category "Alpha", "Bravo" and "Charlie"

1. When the user click "Add to cart" the function must check if the cart is empty, if the cart is empty the function must reset a global variable named $restricted_item_cart
2. After that the function, must check, if the product category of item I want add to the cart is contain into the array where I have place the category "Alpha", "Bravo" and "Charlie"
3. If the item category is contain in the array, the function must add the product id into the global variable $restricted_item_cart

Can you help me please?

NEW EDIT (new code, Im not a pro php coder, can you tell me if is right?):

```
function my_add_woo_cat_classes($classes) {
```

```
global $restricted_cart_items ;
    if ( is_null( $cart )){
            $restricted_cart_items=array();
    }



global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
            break;
    }

$restricted_category= array(11,22);

if (in_array( $product_cat_id, $restricted_category)){
    $current_product= $product->id;
    $restricted_cart_items=array($current_product);
}

return $restricted_cart_items;
}
```

Comment: $restricted_category= array(11,22); What's that line for?.

Comment: This array must contains all product category considered (restricted)

This function must work with all this code: http://pastebin.com/BRU1BP2E

Comment: Yes,but do you need to append items to that array..Or is it just your approach?

Comment: Yes I need append there all the categoriy ID of "restricted" category, this because I need alter dinamically the global variable $restricted_cart_items with only one product by time.

So I need an array with all category ID to make a check from the current product cat and the restricted categories